# Rails6 how to fill text from db into ActionText

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I've been trying for a while now to auto fill a string from my database onto action text, without luck.

```
<%= f.rich_text_area :application,
                     placeholder: 'Hvis du har ansøgt skriftligt, så kan du ligge din ansøgning ind her',
                     value: @application %>
```

Does anyone know how to do this since value don't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rich_text_area](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-rich_text_area) has no value parameter. So you can't set value with rich_text_area. Maybe [rich_text_area_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.0/classes/ActionText/TagHelper.html#method-i-rich_text_area_tag) can solve the problem. You need to set the `name`. Try to set the name by adding the model name (if there is) to attribute name like this: `your_model_name[application]`. For example, if you created the form like `form_with(@foo, ..)` it should be `foo[application]`. You need to specify the correct name.

```
<%= rich_text_area_tag "your_model_name[application]",
                     placeholder: 'Hvis du har ansøgt skriftligt, så kan du ligge din ansøgning ind her',
                     value: @application %>
```

If `@application` has html tags and the content does not appear correctly, try `@application.html_safe`.

Comment: it kinda works but now i cannot save to db... is there no way to inject text into actionText?

Comment: @Kaspervh It's injecting to actionText but not saving to db? You need to set name correctly. Can you share the form method?

Comment: @Kaspervh If you created the form like form_with(@foo, ..), try `<%= rich_text_area_tag "foo[application]", placeholde.. %>`